# What is the correct way to ensure signing failed due to password mismatch in AspNet core Identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have JWTBearer based authentication. The problem that I face is that when signing fails, it just return `result.Succeeded=false`. But I can't find a way to ensure the failure reason was password mismatch, as the same result is returned when Email is not confirmed or User is locked out.
As a workaround, If the Failure reason is not one of the properties provided by `Result` then I assume it is password mismatch.
Here is the code,

```
GenericApiErrorCollection errors = new GenericApiErrorCollection(); 
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync
            (x => x.NormalizedUserName == loginUser.UserName.ToUpperInvariant());

if (user == null)
{
   errors.AddError(ErrorResponsCodes.UserDoesnotExist);
}
else
{
   var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginUser.Password, false);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
       var token = AccessTokenFor(user);
       var refreshToken = await RefreshTokenForAsync(user, loginUser.ClientId);
       return Ok(new { token, refreshToken });
   }
   else
   {
       if (result.IsLockedOut)
       {
            errors.AddError(ErrorResponsCodes.UserLockedOut);
       }
       else if (result.IsNotAllowed)
       {
            errors.AddError(ErrorResponsCodes.UserNotAllowed);
       }
       else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
       {
            errors.AddError(ErrorResponsCodes.UserRequiresTwoFactor);
       }
       else
       {
            errors.AddError(ErrorResponsCodes.UserNamePasswordDoesntMatch);       
       }
    }

}
```

return BadRequest(errors);

Answer (score 1):

"But I can't find a way to ensure the failure reason was password mismatch,"

Because you DO NOT. The best pracice is to say "you could not login". PERIOD. UI wise say "bad password or user does not exist".

If you say "password mismatch" you confirm the user name is valid - which really means I can check for usernames or emails and thus know more of where to redirect the attach to.

Comment: It is an API and UI has its own way of representing the response from here. I am sure UserDoesn'tExist is a bad error and can be merged with PasswordMismatch. But you woul still want to differentiate between user locked out, email not confirmed and Password mismatch. From your answer I can feel that returning PasswordMismatch for everything that doesn't need explicit handling is the right way (similar to what I did).

Comment: No, you do not want. DEFINITELY NOT. If I get "account locked" I KNOW I have the right password and try again later in case the account is open again. You just told me that account AND PASSWORD are correct.

Comment: How do you know that you haven't verified your email, Or you are locked. It is very common for apps to remind that. And about user getting locked, Banking apps are great example.

Comment: Because in order to tell me that the account is locked you need to know the user name is correct.

Comment: The problem here is just the reverse. Username and passwords are correct but the user is not confirmed or locked out. I should inform the user why he is not able to login. isn't that right thing to do?